# How to store ID from database object, to a checkbox in code behind WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, bind

I'm working on WPF application, and I have users, and ofcourse users has some kind of roles, in my case SUPERADMIN AND ADMIN, that roles are stored in table "Roles", One user could have 1 or more roles, so that means one or more checkbox can be selected on my form checkboxes that I generated dynamically on this way:

```
private void LoadRolesToStackPanel()
{
    try
    {
        var roles = RolesController.Instance.SelectAll();

        if (roles.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Role r in roles)
            {
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();

                //cb.Name = r.RoleId.ToString();

                cb.Content = r.Title.ToString();
                cb.FontSize = 15;
                stackRole.Children.Add(cb);
            }
        }


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Later when I'm saving User I need to get ID from checked combobox because it is representing Role acctually, so I need to make insert to database with corresponding RoleId..

Here is how I took selected checkboxes on event SaveUser:

```
IEnumerable<CheckBox> selectedBoxes =
        from checkbox in this.stackRole.Children.OfType<CheckBox>()
        where checkbox.IsChecked.Value
        select checkbox;

foreach (CheckBox box in selectedBoxes)
{
// do something 
}
```

As it is possible to notice I can get Title from combobox because I said

```
cb.Content = r.Title.ToString();
```

But I need ID of "r" - role also, and I don't know how to add it to a checkbox on way I added Title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "correct" way of solving this would be to use an `ItemsControl` that you bind to an `IEnumerable<Role>`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Roles}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Title}" FontSize="15" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

---

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly ViewModel _viewModel = new ViewModel();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = _viewModel;
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Roles = RolesController.Instance.SelectAll();
    }

    public List<Role> Roles { get; private set; }
}
```

This means that you should add an `IsChecked` property to the `Role` class (or create a new client application specific `Role` class that has this property and use this one instead of your current `Role` class).

You could then iterate through the selected roles, either in the code-behind of the view or in the view model:

```
foreach (var role in _viewModel.Roles)
{
    if(role.IsSelected)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

This solution is built on MVVM which is *the* recommended design pattern to use when developing XAML based user interface applications. You should learn it. You could read more about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx.

Comment: @My friend I will try to apply this solution very soon :) Thx for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because noone answered on this question for like 1 hour, I think it's ok to post answer by myself because I've found some kind of solution, I don't know is it good but it works, well for selected Check Boxes because they are acctually generated from Database (Roles) it is possible to do something like this:

```
private void LoadRolesToStackPanel()
{
    try
    {
        var roles = RolesController.Instance.SelectAll();
        if (roles.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Role r in roles)
            {
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();

                cb.Tag = r;

                cb.Content = r.Title.ToString();
                cb.FontSize = 15;
                stackRole.Children.Add(cb);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

foreach (CheckBox box in selectedBoxes)
{
    Role r = (Role)box.Tag;
    //Here we get Id and every other Property that Role had
    var x = r.Id;
}
```

So I included .Tag property and assigned real object from DB to that tag, so I could later easily access to a properties of that DB object from my selected checkbox!

First time I see this guy "Tag" but it is awesome, and I would please anyone with bigger experience with "Tag" to explain to us why does this works like this, and how come it's so easy to access object with .Tag propery.