# How to mark user's role which is represented by dynamically created checkbox on DataGrid selection changed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm working on WPF application, and I have users, and ofcourse users has some kind of roles, in my case SUPERADMIN AND ADMIN, that roles are stored in table "Roles", One user could have 1 or more roles, so that means one or more checkboxes can be selected on my form. I generated checkBoxes dinamically:

I'm adding checkboxes to a stack panel which orientation is Vertical so it looks like this after **applying method below:**

[image]

```
private void LoadRolesToStackPanel()
{
    try
    {
        var roles = RolesController.Instance.SelectAll();

        if (roles.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Role r in roles)
            {
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();

                //cb.Name = r.RoleId.ToString();

                cb.Content = r.Title.ToString();
                cb.FontSize = 15;
                stackRole.Children.Add(cb);
            }
        }


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Now I am wondering how could I show/mark/check or whatever appropriate checkboxes for each user when I'm selecting another user (users are containted in DataGrid dtgUsers so I'm firing dtgUsers_SelectionChanged event when I'm changing selection from user to user, and as I am doing it I need also to show appropriate check boxes as representation of roles and they must be checked of course as representation that selected user has that (Selected) role ).

**Right now I did it on this way, and I think it is very bad approach, so I am asking for new or better solution of doing this.**

```
private void dtgUsers_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

    if (dtgUsers.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        stackRole.Children.Clear();

        User user = (User)(dtgUsers.SelectedItem);

        if (user != null)
        {
            //Get all roles from database for selected user

            user.Roles = RolesController.SelectByUserId(user.Id);

            if (user.Roles.Count > 0)
            {
                //This is bad approach I took Title of each user's role to compare it with all existing roles
                var roleNames = user.Roles.Select(r => r.Title);

                var allRoles = RolesController.SelectAll();

                if (allRoles.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Role r in allRoles)
                    {
                        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();

                        cb.Content = r.Title.ToString();
                        cb.FontSize = 15;
                        cb.Tag = r;
                        stackRole.Children.Add(cb);

                        if (roleNames.Contains(cb.Content)) //Here I'm bassically as I am creating checkbox immediatelly checking/marking it if it exist in user's roles 
                            cb.IsChecked = true;
                    }
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Any kind of suggestion how should I fix this/make it better is very welcome!
Thanks guys
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you in a previous answer you should check out the MVVM design pattern if you want to do this using best practices:

[How to store ID from database object, to a checkbox in code behind WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43263611/how-to-store-id-from-database-object-to-a-checkbox-in-code-behind-wpf)

Then you could simply bind the `ItemsControl` where the roles are displayed to the currently selected user in the `DataGrid`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Roles, ElementName=dtgUsers}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Title}" FontSize="15" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The roles list will then be updated automatically when you select an item in the `DataGrid`.

Comment: I will try to implement is very soon, but by looking at your code I couldn't recognize how could I loop throught selected roles? I saw this piece of code in previous answer : foreach (var role in _viewModel.Roles)
{
    if(role.IsSelected)
    {
        //...
    }
} And this means loop throught all roles but do something only if role is selected?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The IsSelected property of a role will be set to true when you check the CheckBox provided that you have bounded the IsChecked property to the IsSelected property.